# How to extract nominal labels for d3 chart

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, pandas

I'm struggling to get used to accessing and manipulating data objects in d3.

Essentially, I'm trying to create bar chart reflect the average price of a property based on whether its address is in a `Way`, `Close`, `Street`, `Avenue`.

I've munged the data using Pandas in Python and then exported the data with three columns of `district`, `street_split` and `value`.

The district column is to be used as a key to swap between values of the same street names in neighbouring patches.

[Here's](http://plnkr.co/edit/9N6hgl?p=preview) the Plunk for the code and json

I've used nest to key the data on `district` and then on `street_split` thus:

```
var nested_data = d3.nest()
                                .key( function(d){
                                    return d['district']})
                                .key(function(d) { return d.street_split; })                                
                                .entries(data);
```

While I can access the first level key for a dropDown selector box with code along with the lines of:

```
options.text(function (d) { return d.key; })
                    .attr("value", function (d) { return d.key; });
```

I can't work out how to access the `street_split` level.

The best I could find from Google was the extent function, but that only returns the limits (as it should).

```
// Find range of street_name column
          var street_extent = d3.extent(data, function(d) {
              return d['street_split'];
          });
```

I am seeking advice or a resource to get to grips with this query basic data manipulation in d3.

If it helps, I found [this](http://bl.ocks.org/phoebebright/raw/3176159/) extremely useful for understanding d3.nest.

Answer (score 0):

The way I did it was to create a set of every value of the street_extent column based on the original, un-nested data, like this:

```
var street_extent = d3.set();

data.forEach(function(d) {
                    street_extent.add(d['street_split']);

                });
```

Then created a variable containing those labels:

```
var street_labels = street_extent.values();
```

And then plugging that into the scale using the rangeRoundBands method

```
var street_scale = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .rangeRoundBands([0+margin, width], .1)
            .domain(street_labels);
```