# How to use d3 filter and update function to toggle between data selections

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, pandas

I'm trying to get to grips with d3 by creating a bar chart of house prices based on whether the property address ends with 'Street', 'Road', 'Way' etc.

However, I'd also like the view of the data to change based on a column of data for local neighbourhoods.

It's the second query on this topic. Here's the previous query - [How to extract nominal labels for d3 chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32017268/how-to-extract-nominal-labels-for-d3-chart)

You can see the structure of the data extracted through Pandas' to_json function here: http://plnkr.co/edit/He3yPUfuE8k7hvIkupjS?p=preview

I've used a nest function to key the data on the the local areas, but can't work out how to plug in a d3.filter method to restrict the data to a selected area.

I've got a function which creates a select button based on the keys:

```
var options = dropDown.selectAll("option")
           .data(nested_data)

         .enter()
           .append("option");


          options.text(function (d) { return d.key; })
                                    .attr("value", function (d) { return d.key; });
```

But what I can't work out is how to plug the value from this selection into the plotting part of the d3 script.

```
d3.select("svg")
            .selectAll("circle")
            .data(nested_data)
            .enter()
            .append("circle")


          d3.selectAll("circle")            
            .attr("cx", function(d) {
                console.log(d["street_name"]);
                return street_scale(d["street_name"]);
            })
            .attr("cy", function(d) {
                return price_scale(d["value"]);
            })
            .attr("r", 5)
            .attr("fill", "steelblue");
```

And while I know I need an update function to continue to change the chart as users select between, I've not found an example that I can adapt.

Thank you in advance for your patience - I'm very new to d3 and a Javascript noob.

Comment: In the end what value will the bar represent?  The sum of values for that street type in that district?  The mean?  Median?

Comment: @Mark the value represented is the mean of properties sold in that district over the past year. I've done the aggregating in Pandas, but can't work out the way to turn those figures into something useful. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @Mark Please call me out if I've not used the nest function properly. I'm still trying to get to grips with the data functions in d3 and just thought the key would help.

Comment: give me a couple minutes, working up an answer.  I think the nest function is over-complicating things.  You can work with much simpler data structures to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think about the data structure you want in the end.  Since `d3` likes arrays of objects and you want to filter by district, I'm picturing this:

```
var data = {
  district1: [
    {
      street_split: 'a',
      value: 1
    },{
      street_split: 'b',
      value: 2
    }
 ],
 district2: [
    {
      street_split: 'a',
      value: 1
    },{
      street_split: 'b',
      value: 2
    }
 ],
 etc...
```

Your filter then simply becomes:

```
data[someDistrict]
```

So, how do we get your data in this format.  I'd do everything in one loop, the data, the extents, the labels, etc...:

```
  var orgData = {}, // our final data like above
      street_labels = d3.set(), // set of streets
      districts = d3.set(), // set of districts
      minVal = 1e99, // min of values
      maxVal = -1e99; //max of values
  data.forEach(function(d){
    d.value = +d.value; // convert to numeric
    street_labels.add(d.street_split); // set of street_labels
    districts.add(d.district); // set of districts
    if (d.value < minVal) minVal = d.value; // new min?
    if (d.value > maxVal) maxVal = d.value; //new max?
    if (!orgData[d.district]){ // we want a associate array with keys of districts
      orgData[d.district] = []; // and values that are arrays of object
    }
    orgData[d.district].push({ // those objects are street_split and value
      street_split: d.street_split,
      value: d.value
    });
  });
```

Now how do we update on a different select?  That simply becomes:

```
dropDown.on("change", function() {
    d3.selectAll("circle")
      .data(orgData[this.value]) // new data
      .attr("cx", function(d) { // update attributes
        return street_scale(d.street_split);
      })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return price_scale(d.value);
      });
  });
```

Here's my [working code](http://plnkr.co/edit/HwzD4SpROPyjsW0REkfJ?p=preview).

Comment: I really appreciate that answer. It's clearly set out with a goal, with great comments and clear logic. Thank you for your time.