# why doesn't my chart update?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I can't work out why my chart doesn't update when I change selection.

Here's my code so far on [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/iEh9IKiYtGy6Cpk00yGE?p=preview)

The code that seemingly doesn't work is:

```
dropDown.on("change", function() {
    d3.selectAll("circle")
      .data(orgData[this.value])
      .attr("y", function(d) {
        return height - price_scale(d.value);
      })
      .attr("height", function(d) {
        return price_scale(d.value);
    });
  });
```

The code comes from the answer to a previous query that I made:

[How to use d3 filter and update function to toggle between data selections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32026598/how-to-use-d3-filter-and-update-function-to-toggle-between-data-selections)

That code worked because the update function tweaked the parameters of a circle svg object. Is there a parameter I've not factored in with rect objects?

Comment: I don't see any `svg:circle` element, do you mean `rect` instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

circle elements don't have height or y attributes, they have cx, cy and r attributes.

Alternatively maybe you meant to select rect elements which do have height and y attributes.

Comment: Thank you for the swift response. It was a basic error which I should have seen.